# Statistical Tests Would Reject Existence of Rare Diseases? Why?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I was wondering the other day. Given a rare disease that occurs 1 in every thousand. That would infect 7 million people in the world. Yet, most statistical tests, testing for the existence of this disease at even a 1% level would be rejected. How does statistical theory resolve this issue?

Comment: Statistics is not everything. You need common sense more than statistics, and you need logic as much as common sense. Statistical theory makes so many assumptions that if you do not have a complete grasp of them you would be bound to make fallacious inferences. Did you know that there is such a thing as **idiopathy**, and that there are many symptoms that are called **idiopathic** when the cause is not determinable?

Comment: If this question provided a more concrete example of _how_ a statistical test would reject the existence of a rare disease, it might be easier to give  a more complete answer to it. The only way we even know how to describe rare diseases is because we have clinical evidence from people who actually have those diseases. What kind of statistics would contradict that evidence?

Comment: @MorganRodgers: See David's comment for one part of my reason. Think a bit for the other part, which is that statistical theory applies only when certain assumptions are met. To test for existence of a disease using statistical methods would require the relevant assumptions must be checked, otherwise it would just give nonsensical results.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't do a statistical test for whether or not the disease existed.  Rather, you would do a statistical test to test a hypothesis about the prevalence of the disease.  Using a large enough sample size, you could determine whether or not the hypothesis was likely to be accurate (the "% level" of the test refers to the probability that the observed prevalence of the disease closely matches the actual prevalence).

Statistical theory resolves this by dealing with intervals, and probabilities.  You can never be 100% sure of something without looking at every member of the population.  Testing a sample, you can say something like "we are 99% sure that less than .0001% of the population has this disease".  This uses an assumption about the percentage of the population, using this you obtain a range of values that would be likely to occur from a random sample from the population, and you compare this to the data you obtain from an actual sample.  But you are working with statistics, so you are not dealing with absolutes.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question (how to test for existence of a rare disease, not how to test for prevalence of a disease).

Comment: Oh you interpret that there is a misunderstanding. Fair enough. His question does explicitly say "testing for the existence of this disease" though.